# learning javascript, need clarification on variables values

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a JS tutorial and long story short, we have to get certain amounts of numbers and pass them to HTML table/cells with ids of "square". the code works but im not sure how. Im confused in 2 parts. (below the code)

```
window.onload = newCard;

function newCard() {
    for(var i=0; i<24; i++){
        setSquare( i )
    }
    function setSquare (thisSquare) {
        var currSquare = "square" + thisSquare; 
        var newNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*75 )+1
        document.getElementById(currSquare).innerHTML = newNum;
    }
}
```

1. the first function `newCard`, after the loop is done, sets its final values and then passes it `setSquare` which is the next function below it. What I dont get is...assuming that the parsing goes from top to bottom, `setSquare` isnt defined yet so shouldnt it return an error?
2. My confusion about parsing and distributing values aside, on the second function.

   ```
   var currSquare = "square" + thisSquare;
   ```

   `setSquare` in the second function now has the number values from function one that it was passed. variable `currSquare` is taking the `"square"` id from main HTML table and adding into it the value from function 1 above. my quesiton is, how does javascript know that `"square"` in function 2 is a id and not a string? further more because of it,

   ```
   document.getElementById(currSquare).innerHTML = newNum;
   ```

   there IS no ID on main page of `currSquare` so how can it "get" it and pass it `newNum` if there is no such thing? `currSquare` is a variable.

Comment: It shouldn't fail. Functions don't have to be defined before they are being called. JavaScript isn't C. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion is understandable, but there are a few things that you're overlooking.

First, when you set `windows.onload = newCard`, you're telling the browser to call the `newCard` function when the document finishes loading.

When the document finishes loading, all the parsing has been already done, so all the variable and function definitions have been made, and, saved some syntax error, all should be well.

The line:

```
var currSquare = "square" + thisSquare;
```

simply concatenetes the string `"square"` with the string representation of the number in the `thisSquare` variable. When dealing with different types, most modern languages try to find a common denominator between the operands.

As for the `document.getElementById()` function, in your HTML it MUST have some sort of identifiers in the format `squareXXX` where XXX is a number from 0 to 23. Otherwise the code wouldn't work and an exception would be thrown saying that there was no such id.

Comment: `getElementById` does not throw an exception if an element with such an ID does not exist. It simply returns `null`.

Comment: That's true, Felix, but the line `getElementById(id).innerHTML = ''` would, because there would be no valid object. And in the sample code that the OP presented, the exception would be thrown with the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

> assuming that the parsing goes from top to bottom, setSquare isnt defined yet so shouldn't it return an error?

Function declarations are *hoisted to the top* of the containing scope. `function setSquare() {}` is a function declaration, so your code is effectively the same as declaring the function before the loop:

```
function setSquare (thisSquare) {
    //...
}
for(var i=0; i<24; i++){
    setSquare( i )
}
```

> how does javascript know that "square" in function 2 is a id and not a string?

It does not. It is a string and is treated as such. There is nothing like an "id datatype" in JavaScript. `currSquare` is a variable containing the string `"squareX"` where X is the value from `thisSquare` (0 to 23).

> there IS no ID on main page of `currSquare` so how can it "get" it

`document.getElementById` expects a string as argument. This string should be an id of some element. There is nothing special about this. Instead of passing a literal string, you are passing the one contained in `currSquare` (just like you pass the integer contained in `i` to `setSquare`).

---

It seems you have not fully understood the basics yet, although your are doing a tutorial. Maybe the [*MDC JavaScript Guide*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) will help you more. Read especially about [*Values, Variables, and Literals*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals) and [*Functions and function scope*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Comment: Thanks Felix. let me ask u another? based on your comment above "There is nothing like an "id datatype". so since in my html i have an id of the area i want affected, how does JS know to choose that id selector i defined in html and not say , some random sentence with the word "square" in it.? thanks again schoolin a noob

Comment: @somdow: Because `document.getElementById` is defined like that. It searches for an HTML element which has an attribute `id` equal to the name you passed to the function. It does inspect any content or other attributes. [You can find more information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById). Other functions are for example, `document.getElementsByTagName`, which returns a list of elements with a certain tag. E.g. `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` would return all links.